# Broken corners of UITextfield when custom masking is applied

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, cashapelayer

I am trying to create a textfield with left corners rounded off. For that I've used the following code to apply masking. Now the corners of the textfield are trimmed off. Any idea why?

```
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.bounds = textfieldContainerView.frame
    shape.position = textfieldContainerView.center
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: textfieldContainerView.bounds,
                              byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft],
                              cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)).cgPath
    textfieldContainerView.layer.mask = shape
    textfieldContainerView.layer.borderColor = ColorKit.smoke.cgColor
    textfieldContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Here's how it looks like (notice the broken corners on the left).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works with a lower value of radius and height , for example 4. 
Also, the broken corners height continues to increase with increase in value of radius/height

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
textfieldContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
textfieldContainerView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
```

Also, this will work if your Deployment Target is 11.0 and above.